# How to search a Perl array for a string that changes each iteration

Tags: arrays, string, perl, search, hashtable

I have looked at documentation, and I know how to search an array for a string, print the string's location, etc. But my issue is that my string changes for each iteration. My goal is to search the first row of an array for a string, save its location, then search the first column of the array for a different string, and save that location (giving me a row, column location in the array). Here is the code of an "idea" I want to execute:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $subseq1 = 'MNIDDKL';
my $subseq2 = 'GLFLKCGGIDEMQSS';
my $line;
my @array;
my @arr;
while($line = <MATFILE>) #Load the array
{
    $line =~ /^$/ and die "Blank line detected at $.\n";
    $line =~ /^#/ and next;
    push @array, $line; #adds each line to the array
};
close MATFILE;

#Join then split
my $joined = join('', @array);
my @rep = $joined =~/./g;
@rep = split(' ', $joined);

#Need to split into row, column format:
while (@rep)
{
    push (@arr, [splice(@rep, 0, 24)]);
}
my ($len1, $len2) = map length, $subseq1, $subseq2;
my @subseq1 = $subseq1 =~ /./g;
my @subseq2 = $subseq2 =~ /./g;
for my $x (0..$len2) #Number of rows
{
    for my $y (0..$len1) #Number of columns
    {
        if ($subseq1[$y] == $arr[0][$_]) #Does not work 
        {
        my $subcol = $_; #column from the sub matrix
        }

    if ($subseq2[$x] == $arr[$_][0]) #Does not work
        {
        my $subrow = $_; #row from pam matrix
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I can use List::MoreUtils 'first_index' to find the first location of my string, but I am unsure how to do this as my string changes.

Overall, I am looking to find the character in each string ('A' and 'R' for example), find one in the first row of the array, find the other in the first column of the array, and associate a location for it. Any and all help is appreciated!

Here is the matrix I want to access:

```
#
# PAM 250 substitution matrix, scale = ln(2)/3 = 0.231049
#
# Expected score = -0.844, Entropy = 0.354 bits
#
# Lowest score = -8, Highest score = 17
#
   A  R  N  D  C  Q  E  G  H  I  L  K  M  F  P  S  T  W  Y  V  B  Z  X  *
A  2 -2  0  0 -2  0  0  1 -1 -1 -2 -1 -1 -3  1  1  1 -6 -3  0  0  0  0 -8
R -2  6  0 -1 -4  1 -1 -3  2 -2 -3  3  0 -4  0  0 -1  2 -4 -2 -1  0 -1 -8
N  0  0  2  2 -4  1  1  0  2 -2 -3  1 -2 -3  0  1  0 -4 -2 -2  2  1  0 -8
D  0 -1  2  4 -5  2  3  1  1 -2 -4  0 -3 -6 -1  0  0 -7 -4 -2  3  3 -1 -8
C -2 -4 -4 -5 12 -5 -5 -3 -3 -2 -6 -5 -5 -4 -3  0 -2 -8  0 -2 -4 -5 -3 -8
Q  0  1  1  2 -5  4  2 -1  3 -2 -2  1 -1 -5  0 -1 -1 -5 -4 -2  1  3 -1 -8
E  0 -1  1  3 -5  2  4  0  1 -2 -3  0 -2 -5 -1  0  0 -7 -4 -2  3  3 -1 -8
G  1 -3  0  1 -3 -1  0  5 -2 -3 -4 -2 -3 -5  0  1  0 -7 -5 -1  0  0 -1 -8
H -1  2  2  1 -3  3  1 -2  6 -2 -2  0 -2 -2  0 -1 -1 -3  0 -2  1  2 -1 -8
I -1 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -3 -2  5  2 -2  2  1 -2 -1  0 -5 -1  4 -2 -2 -1 -8
L -2 -3 -3 -4 -6 -2 -3 -4 -2  2  6 -3  4  2 -3 -3 -2 -2 -1  2 -3 -3 -1 -8
K -1  3  1  0 -5  1  0 -2  0 -2 -3  5  0 -5 -1  0  0 -3 -4 -2  1  0 -1 -8
M -1  0 -2 -3 -5 -1 -2 -3 -2  2  4  0  6  0 -2 -2 -1 -4 -2  2 -2 -2 -1 -8
F -3 -4 -3 -6 -4 -5 -5 -5 -2  1  2 -5  0  9 -5 -3 -3  0  7 -1 -4 -5 -2 -8
P  1  0  0 -1 -3  0 -1  0  0 -2 -3 -1 -2 -5  6  1  0 -6 -5 -1 -1  0 -1 -8
S  1  0  1  0  0 -1  0  1 -1 -1 -3  0 -2 -3  1  2  1 -2 -3 -1  0  0  0 -8
T  1 -1  0  0 -2 -1  0  0 -1  0 -2  0 -1 -3  0  1  3 -5 -3  0  0 -1  0 -8
W -6  2 -4 -7 -8 -5 -7 -7 -3 -5 -2 -3 -4  0 -6 -2 -5 17  0 -6 -5 -6 -4 -8
Y -3 -4 -2 -4  0 -4 -4 -5  0 -1 -1 -4 -2  7 -5 -3 -3  0 10 -2 -3 -4 -2 -8
V  0 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -1 -2  4  2 -2  2 -1 -1 -1  0 -6 -2  4 -2 -2 -1 -8
B  0 -1  2  3 -4  1  3  0  1 -2 -3  1 -2 -4 -1  0  0 -5 -3 -2  3  2 -1 -8
Z  0  0  1  3 -5  3  3  0  2 -2 -3  0 -2 -5  0  0 -1 -6 -4 -2  2  3 -1 -8
X  0 -1  0 -1 -3 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -1  0  0 -4 -2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -8
* -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8  1
```

I will be accessing these values and using them to compute a score for sequence similarity.

Comment: Can you show some data, and point out what parts you need from that?

Comment: So, for {A,R}, you want -2?

Comment: That is correct @ikegami

Comment: A HoH would make far more sense than an AoA, then. In fact, I'd use a simple hash keyed by a 2-letter string.

Comment: `==` is for comparing numbers. You want `eq` to compare strings. `use warnings;` would have told you that.

Comment: You are using `$_` as a element index, but you never assign anything to `$_`. `use warnings;` would have told you that.

Comment: You assign something to `@rep`, then immediately assign something else. That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my %score_lookup;
{
   my $found_header = 0;
   my @col_ids;
   while (<>) {
      next if /^#/;

      if ($found_header) {
         my ($row_id, @fields) = split;
         for my $i (0..$#fields) {
            my $col_id = $col_ids[$i];
            my $score = $fields[$i];
            $score_lookup{ $row_id . $col_id } = $score;
         }
      } else {
         $found_header = 1;
         @col_ids = split;
      }
   }
}

my $score = $score_lookup{ "A" . "R" };   # -2
```